# Is it true that $P((-z \leq Z \leq z) = \alpha = 2(P(Z \leq z) = \alpha/2)$ by symmetry?

Tags: normal-distribution

I have a question:

> Is it true that $$P((-z \leq Z \leq z) = \alpha = 2(P(Z \leq z) = \alpha/2)$$ by symmetry?

So you really only need to find one value of $z$?

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: The parentheses do not match in your question. But after you fix the question, **sketch** the standard normal distribution, indicate on it which **area** corresponds to $P(-z \leq Z \leq z)$ and see if whether your corrected equation makes any sense.

Comment: I think you are equating wrongly the $\alpha$'s in your question. It doesn't make sense that $P(Z\leq z)=\alpha/2$ if you define $P(-z\leq Z\leq z)=\alpha$. I suggested some thoughts in order to solve this in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect this is homework and, if it isn't, it's somewhat straightforward to prove (given that you fix the values of $\alpha$). Let's assume that, as @DilipSarwate in the comments pointed out, you meant to express $P(-z\leq Z\leq z)=\alpha$ in terms of $P(Z\leq z)$ (which is **NOT** equal to $\alpha/2$ according to your definition of $\alpha$, can you see, at least geometrically, why this is so?):

1. Can you re-express $P(-z\leq Z\leq z)$ in terms of the CDFs $P(Z\leq z)$ and $P(Z\leq -z)$?
2. With part 1. done, can you re-express $P(Z\leq -z)$ in terms of $P(Z\leq z)$? (write the integral and perform a suitable change of variables).
3. Once you've done it, check you answer by replacing $P(Z\leq z)=(1+\alpha)/2$ (i.e., the real function of $\alpha$ for $P(Z\leq z)$: now we can see it isn't equal to $\alpha/2$!). Does that make sense in terms of areas under the curve, i.e., it is ok to you that the area $P(Z\leq z)=(1+\alpha)/2$ is greater than that of $P(-z\leq Z\leq z)=\alpha$?

**EDIT:** as was written in the answer of @MichaelChernick, maybe you meant to express $P(-z\leq Z\leq z)=\alpha$ in terms of $P(0\leq Z\leq z)=\alpha/2$. If that's the case, see his answer! After this one, it should make a lot of sense to you (and you can even derive it following similar steps as here).

Comment: It would be $\Phi(z)-\Phi(-z)$ for part 1.

Comment: That's part 1! Do parts 2 and 3 now :-).

Answer (score 0):

I think the author meant $P(0<Z<z) = \alpha/2$ when $P(-z<Z<z) = \alpha$ by symmetry whereas @Néstor has taken the interval to be from $-\infty$ to $z$ which would be $(1+\alpha)/2$.
The symmetry argument is that $P(-z<Z<z) = \alpha = P(-z<Z<0) + P(0<Z<z)$ and since by symmetry $P(-z<Z<0) = P(0<Z<z)$ so $\alpha = 2 P(0<Z<z)$ or $P(0<Z<z) = \alpha/2$.

Comment: I think the author meant P(0<Z<z) = α/2 when P(-z<Z<z) = α by symmetry whereas Nestor has taken the interval to be from minus infinity to z which would be (1+α)/2.
The symmetry argument is that P(-z<Z<z) = α = P(-z<Z<0) + P(0<Z<z) and since by symmetry 
P(-z<Z<0) = P(0<Z<z) so α = 2 P(0<Z<z) or P(0<Z<z) = α/2 .

Comment: Michael, you wrote your answer in your comments (I suspect that you did it by mistake). And now that you mention it, yes, maybe the author meant to express $P(-z<Z<z)=\alpha$ as $P(0<Z<z)=\alpha/2$!

Comment: I meant for that comment to be my answer but it got messed up when I tried to enter it.

Comment: You can still edit your answer and paste it there!